# Static IP address in WIn 10 doesnt work like in Win 7

Tags: networking, ip

I inherited network sistem in the school. In a school room teacher's computer has 2 network cards. One card shares its internet connection and is set up as dynamic IP and the other card is set up with static IP address for example:

- IP address 192.168.11.1
- Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway 192.168.1.1
- Prefered DNS server 192.168.1.1

Students PCs are connected throuogh switch to the second card and each students PC has its card set up like this:

- IP address 192.168.11.102
- Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway 192.168.11.1
- Prefered DNS server 192.168.1.1

All PCs are WIn7 and it all works nicely. Then the server(teachers PC) got broken and had to be replaced with new PC with Win 10 on it. When I make an exact copy of the settting above the Win 10 system doesnt give students internet, they can work on local LAN but cant get to the net. I am not aware of any differences in networking between these Windows versions but it somehow doesnt work. Any idea?

Comment: First thing to do, IMHO, would be to start up Wireshark and simply compare the differences between what Win10 clients do and what Win7 clients do.

Comment: What did the dynamic configured interface look before and how does the new one look (in terms of configuration)? As you do have a third component set as the default gateway there has to be some other link or component as well?

Comment: @grawity I have no Win10 clients I tried to change server @ Seth not sure what do you mean with "dynamic interface" If its about network card its all set to dynamic so its the same The third component is the ruter that accepts the traffic from server(teachers PC), but I havent changed anything anywhere

Comment: Ah, right, did not notice that. Well, in that case I guess you just forgot to enable IP forwarding on the teacher's PC – it is _not_ on by default. Check if the old system had "Internet Connection Sharing" active.

Comment: @grawity I am not sure about IP forwarding isnt that thing of the router?, but I did setup internet connection sharing on both system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the follow up with this issue and the solution.
On new computer with Win 10 I removed Win10 and installed Win 7 and had the same issue that Internet connection Sharing didnt work as on old Win 7 machine. 
After some more online searching I found that ICS sets its own static IP and that if you want to use your IP range instead of default 192.168.137.1 you have to modify registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters and change ScopeAddress and StandaloneDHCPAddress to the static IP that is needed, and it works!

Answer (score 2):

The OS *does not* automatically forward packets between interfaces, so merely having two network cards and configuring subnets is not enough to turn the teacher's computer into a router.

At minimum you need to enable IP forwarding – on client versions of Windows, you can do that by enabling "Internet Connection Sharing" (ICS), or by changing a few registry settings.

If you're stuck with Windows as a router, then ICS is the preferred option since it will also perform SNAT and provide DHCP to the students' network.

Comment: As I said in the OP one card (on server) that has its setting on dynamic is sharing its internet connetion or in other word has enabled(checked) "Internet connection sharing". The clients Pcs dont have that setup as they have only one card with wich they connect to switch that is connected to second network card of the server and has static IP as said in OP.

Comment: Is the firewall on?